# How to use "make"?

Tags: grammar

> She decided to make running at least one mile a part of school day to supplement regular PE,class.

Why use "running" rather than "run"?

Answer (score 1):

That's because *running at least one mile* is the object of the verb *make*. She decided to make something a part of school day to supplement regular PE class and that something was running at least one mile. We could ask this question and get the following answer:

> *Question*: She decided to make **what** a part of school day to supplement regular PE class?
>   *Answer*: **Running at least one mile**.

*Running* is being used as a noun and the whole thing, *running at least one mile*, is a noun phrase. *Make run at least one mile a part of school day* sounds wrong and makes no sense in this context.

Comment: You don't have to explain this to me, but learners might wonder how this answers the OP's question. After all, _run_ can also be used as a noun, so why is it "make running" and not "make run"?

Comment: I see what you mean, but I think the OP is just parsing the sentence wrong. **Make run at least one mile a part of school day** makes zero sense in this context.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but it can be hard for a learner to understand why it doesn't work grammatically. (And the question does ask "why".) Also, it's interesting how we could say: _She decided to run at least one mile_, or even: _She decided to take a one-mile run._

Comment: I guess we have to ask the OP why he thinks that *run* would be a better option than *running* in that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> *She decided to make running at least one mile a part of the school day to*
>   *supplement regular PE class*.

"Make" is a catenative verb but it only occurs in complex catenative constructions (the kind with an intervening NP), e.g. *I'll make them run a mile every day.*

Thus since your example is not a catenative construction, this a case where, exceptionally, there are sufficient grounds to include the non-finite clause "running at least one mile" within the direct object type of internal complement with "a part of school day" as objective predicative complement, cf. *She made regular exercise a requirement*.

Note, though, that "**running at least one mile**" **is** **not a noun phrase**, since "running" has the noun phrase "at least one mile" as direct object, and nouns don't take direct objects.

Comment: English is my only language and I read this and know less now than i did before reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Examples for the purpose of re-use:

**to make something something**

- To make good grades [his,her,my etc.] goal.
- He wants to make good grades his goal.
- He wants to make long-distance running his goals.
- She decided to make running a part of her regular exercise.

running is a sport and the noun is running for the sport. It is also used adjectivally: running sports as opposed to water sports, for example.

If running is what you do for exercise, you go for runs (jogging) or you run around a track. Run is another noun which is the name of the actual activity. You can go for a run but not be into running (the sport) in a major way.

Also, there is ski run (the path or place you ski down the mountain).